# Signing Android App built with Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, jarsigner

I have built an app (with Apache Cordova). I want to sign it. I follow this instructions.
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

After

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk `alias_name`
```

I get this:

`jarsigner error: java.security.SignatureException: private key algorithm is not compatible with signature algorithm`

I have create the unsigned app file like this:

```
..../my_application$ cordova build android --release
```

I have put the file `my_application.apk` in the same folder as `my-release-key.keystore`, of course.

What can I do?

Comment: did you create your `KEY` (keystore) using `RSA` algorithm?

Comment: Create your keystore within AndroidStudio or Bundle Eclipse. Probably the Key is incompatible